# How to show Alert when UIApplication is not able to open URL?

Tags: ios, web, uiapplication

This method opens up the url in Safari when the website string is not null and it is atleast of length 3. But when I have supplierWebsite=@"www.heritage.com", nothing happens. I know that heritage.com is not valid website and so it is not activating in UIApplication. I would like to display atleast a pop up that would tell user that website is not available. Is there any way i can show Alertview telling that website is not available.

```
- (IBAction)doWebOpen:(UIButton *)sender {

if (self.provider.supplierWebSite && [self.provider.supplierWebSite length] > 3) {
    NSString *urlString = [self.provider supplierWebSite];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];

}else {

    NSError *err = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"com.cantopenweb" code:509 andDescription:@"This supplier does not have a website."];
    [self showErrorAlert:err];
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `canOpenURL` of [**UIApplication**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class, like:

```
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url])
 {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
 }
 else
 {
   //show alert
 }
```

---

> **canOpenURL:**
>
> **Returns whether an application can open a given URL resource.**
>
> `- (BOOL)canOpenURL:(NSURL *)url`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> **url**
>
> ```
> A URL object that identifies a given resource. The URL’s scheme—possibly a custom scheme—identifies which application can
> ```
>
> handle the URL.
>
> **Return Value**
>
> NO if no application is available that will accept the URL; otherwise,
>   returns YES. Discussion
>
> This method guarantees that that if openURL: is called, another
>   application will be launched to handle it. It does not guarantee that
>   the full URL is valid. Availability
>
> ```
> Available in iOS 3.0 and later.
> ```
>
> Declared In UIApplication.h

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what i want.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use canOpenURL method,

> [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL 
>   URLWithString:@"your website"]];

The method returns a BOOL, so check that for YES or NO.

If YES, it CAN else NO.